# Predict function giving error for XGBoost but running for GBM in H2O

Tags: python, h2o, xgboost, sparkling-water, xgbclassifier

I am making a classification model using H2O in python. I am able to build a GBM model and make predictions on training and test dataset whereas when I build an XGBoost model and try to make predictions.

Below is the GBM code: (Runs perfectly fine)

```
from h2o.estimators.gbm import H2OGradientBoostingEstimator

model_rf_v3 = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(model_id='mojo_test_v4', ntrees=259, max_depth=6, categorical_encoding = 'OneHotExplicit', learn_rate = 0.1)

model_rf_v3.train(y = myResponse_rf,x = myCat + myNum, training_frame=hf_train_h2o,
            validation_frame = hf_test_h2o)

pred = model_rf_v3.predict(hf_test_h2o)[:,2]
```

XGBoost code: (Fails)

```
from h2o.estimators.xgboost import H2OXGBoostEstimator

model_rf_vn = H2OXGBoostEstimator(ntrees=259, learn_rate = 0.05, stopping_metric = "misclassification", categorical_encoding = 'OneHotExplicit', tree_method="hist", grow_policy="lossguide", max_depth = 9)

model_rf_vn.train(y = myResponse_rf,x = myCat + myNum, training_frame=hf_train_h2o,
            validation_frame = hf_test_h2o)

pred = model_rf_vn.predict(hf_test_h2o)[:,2] ## Error at this point
```

Error:

```
job with key $0300ffffffff$_9cacec5e7e4540e343f43ac2ce3e459e failed with an exception: DistributedException from ha880datanode-14.fab4.prod.booking.com/10.220.205.163:54321: '63', caused by java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 63"
```

If the error would have been in dataset, I think GBM should also given an error. Does the predict function for XGBoost work in a different way or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance,

Vishal

Comment: Could you mention what h2o-3 version you are using and email the full exception msg/logs to support@h2o.ai?

Comment: @Neema I am using H2O cluster version 3.26.11. Sure, I would send the full log to h2o.ai